# Why wasn't the MSL landing ellipse in Gale Crater placed further South?

Tags: curiosity, entry-descent-landing, mars-science-laboratory, site-selection, gale

[This paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11214-012-9916-y) documents the final landing site selection process for the Mars Science Laboratory (MSL) mission. One of the cons associated with Gale Crater (as pointed out in Table 10 of the paper), was that the prime science targets were outside of the landing ellipse, to the South. Example traverses to these science targets are shown in section 11 of that paper.

My question is: **Why wasn't the landing ellipse placed lower South to overlap with these science targets? In other words, what engineering safety constraint would have been violated if the landing ellipse was further down South?**

The answer might reside in Figures 10 and 11 of the paper, but I have a hard time understanding their significance. According to Figure 10, MOLA slopes above 7.38 degrees seem out of bounds, yet the engineering constraints in Table 3 allow terrain slopes up to 30 degrees. Also, the large black dunes (Bagnold Dunes) do not seem to be an issue either since they already overlap with the proposed landing ellipse, as shown [here](https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/3856/target-for-start-of-driving-by-mars-rover-curiosity/).